# Boxes appearing in online PDF

Tags: pdf, file-format, digital

I work for a magazine and every so often we get ads (PDF format) that run through the pre-flight process with no errors. I will export a PDF with the ads out of InDesign and these boxes appear. This does not show up when we go to print, but we have an online edition which has the boxes. Does anyone know what causes this?
Thanks!

[image: Image of ad with boxes]

Answer (score 0):

They are display anomalies from the transparency flattener. each one of those lines is a bounding box around where some transparency was flattened.

How are you handling the the original art to online edition process?

Comment: The original art comes in as a PDF. I use Acrobat to run a pre-flight for fixes. Is there anything I can do within Acrobat to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Once you preflight in Acrobat, how do you end up with a JPG or PNG (or whatever) to display online? That will be where the boxes are occurring. Or, it it that your online  edition is actually a PDF?

Comment: The online edition is a PDF. I use the "Press Quality" setting in InDesign when I export it.